# A problem about a abelian and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of $2X2$ real matrices:$$\left (\begin {matrix} 
a & b \\
0 & d\\
\end {matrix}\right )$$ where $ad\neq 0$ with respect to the regular matrix product. Let $N$ be the cyclic Group generated by:$$\left (\begin {matrix}
1& b\\
0&1\\
\end {matrix}\right )$$ Prove that the quotient Group $G/N$ is abelian. It is easy to show that $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$. Therefore for each $g\in G$ $Ng=gN$ where where $Ng$ and $gN$ are the right and left coset of $G$. I've tried to come up with a few numerical examples however I was not able to find a couple of matrices $a$ and $b$ such that $abN=baN$

Answer (score 1):

What is the commutator (derived ) subgroup of $\;G\;$ ?:

$$AXA^{-1}X^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\0&z\end{pmatrix}\overbrace{\frac1{ad}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}}^{=A^{-1}}\frac1{xz}\begin{pmatrix}z&-y\\0&x\end{pmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac1{adxz}\begin{pmatrix}ax&ay+bz\\0&dz\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}dz&-dy-bx\\0&ax\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&\beta\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in N$$

so that we have $\;G'\le N\iff G/N\;$ is abelian

Comment: This is the same solution as Sebastian has at the duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. I didn't even see the comment as I was busy typing the above answer. But now I have: other than stating  $\;G'\subset N\;$ , I think my answer is more worked out.

Comment: You are not the only one. Your solution has been given before again, but is now deleted (but can be still seen, if you have 10k rep). I am sure we can work out it even more, but it is no fun repeating over and over again.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. I believe you, because I can't see deleted answers. I guess that such standard questions are usual in most mathematics departments so you'll find such questions again and again. I've been very short time in this site and I've already seen several repeated questions.

Comment: Well, this is probably a discussion for "meta". Some questions are more popular than others, of course.